# JQuery List Traversal using selectors or methods help

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, traversal, loops

I'm basically having a bit of trouble with traversing through an unordered list and retreiving list items.

```
  foreach (MyTypeObject s in result)
        {

            oList.Clear();

             {


            oList.AppendFormat("<ul id='OuteroListItems'>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<ul id='oListItems'>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.Name + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.NameDesc + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.StartDate + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.EndDate + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</ul>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</ul>");

            sb.Append(oList);


        }
```

ok, I basically have a list of items in one unordered list and then an unordered list holding a list of items which hold items initself.

For each one of these I am trying to select the start date

so say I had 3 unordered lists inside of 'OuteroListItems', i would want to select all 3 of these s.StartDates and color them red in 'oListItems'.

I've tried this but it only select the first element in the outer lists 3rd inner list element and coloring that red.

```
   $("ul#OuteroListItems li").each(function(){

    $("ul#oListItems li:eq(2)").css("color", "red");

    });
```

Comment: Take a look on one of the powerful features of jQuery, the traversal methods. http://www.jaftalks.com/Home/Show/Introduction-to-JQuery-Traversal-Methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use class instead of ID :)  [IDs have to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) or you'll get all sorts of funky behavior...when they're not unique it's invalid HTML, just change `id=` in your code to `class=` to fix this.  Your output should now look like this:

```
<ul class='OuteroListItems'>
  <li>
    <ul class='oListItems'>
      <li>s.Name</li>
      <li>s.NameDesc</li>
      <li>s.StartDate</li>
      <li>s.EndDate</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the following selector to get each StartDate `<li>`:

```
$(".oListItems li:nth-child(3)").css("color", "red");​
```

[You can see a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnZtX/)

Comment: Suppose I then wanted to traverse through each one of these list items StartDate and do something with each one, asy some string manipulation, would I then each.() loop the values 

like make that equal to a variable and then $(variable).each(function(){}); 

?

Comment: @Calibre2010 - You can pass a function to `.text()` and `.html()`, whichever you need, here's an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jnZtX/1/ Just change the return to be whatever you want the result set to :)

Comment: nice solution, I think the problem is slightly different from that, what I have managed to is this 
var vv = $(".oListItems li:nth-child(3)").append("---").text();
var v = vv.split('---');

so v is the array now, I just need to go through each of the items in the array. . i have v mapped to what i want to do to each item when it goes through its iteration im just not sure how to go about looping this bit.

Comment: @Calibre2010 - You can use `.map()` to get an array to work with easier, here's how to do that and how to loop through it using `$.each()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jnZtX/2/